# Why is the timestamp in UIDatePicker always off by a few seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm pulling a timestamp out of a UIDatePicker like so:

```
datePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

The timestamps are always off by a seemingly random number of seconds. Given that the UI specifies a whole number of minutes, I'd expect that number to be divisible by 60. For example here's what I just got out of the debugger:

```
(lldb) po self.datePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970
1396655124
```

That number corresponds to Fri, 04 Apr 2014 23:45:24 GMT. Where did the 24 seconds come from?

Comment: Another data point: This only seems to happen for times around the current time. When I choose times that are tomorrow, I get the correct timestamp. I chose a date tomorrow and it returned 1396735200 which is correct: Sat, 05 Apr 2014 22:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 1):

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), "[b]etween their adoption in 1972 and June 2012, 25 leap seconds have been scheduled, all positive."

I'd assume that's where the extra seconds have come from.

Comment: Seems like that should be handled by any timezone converter. Also, it's not consistently the same number of seconds. Both python datetime and epochconverter.com seem to agree that those timestamps aren't a whole number of minutes.